# how to check if a virtual camera has fully transitioned or not in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

I'm working on a C#/Unity project, and I want to know when the cinemachine virtual camera has fully transitioned to another cinemachine camera. I've seen people using [IsBlending](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cinemachinebrain-isblending-not-working-for-state-driven-camera.488117/), but I'm still not sure how to implement that code in my project.

My code is like..

```
  private CinemachineBlend activeBlend = null;
  public bool IsBlending { get { return activeBlend != null; } }
  [SerializeField] private CinemachineVirtualCamera[] virtualCameras;

  void TestItIsWorking()
  {
    virtualCameras[0].Priority = 10;
    virtualCameras[1].Priority = 0; // -> this starts the blending the virtual camera
    Debug.Log("this function is called"); // -> prints "this function is called"
    Debug.Log(IsBlending); // -> prints false
  }
```

So I guess I'm doing something wrong because event the virtual camera has started to change, I get a false value as of IsBlending boolean. I also wrote while loop instead of just Debug logging the IsBlending value, but the result was still the same. I want to run another function right after the blending has finished, so if there is a better solution for this, please also let me know....

Comment: As I understand that property should rather go into the `StateDrivenCamera` script itself ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your activeBlend field getting a reference correctly? Using the IsBlending property of your CinemachineBrain is an option by the way.